# Stop a leak in an outdoor plastic pipe

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe

We had our bathroom refitted a couple of years ago, which required all the waste water piping around the house to be refitted. One of the joins in the pipe carrying all the waste water away from the bathroom was leaky - the plumber applied some kind of paste to fix it.

I have no idea what was used. Whatever it was, the paste has not weathered well and has now essentially turned to powder and fallen away. The leak has returned with a vengeance.

In hopes of stopping the leak I have applied several layers of copious amounts of silicone, of a type that cures when wet. While it has dried successfully, it's only slightly reduced the amount of water in the leak.

I'm not sure why this is: I assume that because it's much thicker and stickier than ordinary silicone, it's not able to completely plug gaps quite as effectively. The surface never dries out - there is a constant drip - which may stop it from forming an effective seal.

What else can I do/try to stop this leak?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the plumber who installed it, and asking what they used originally?  Perhaps the correct strategy is a multi-part seal:  original material on the inside, and then silicone to weatherize it.

Comment: @Nick2253 I have. They are not responding to my calls, which is a shame since they've proved very reliable in the past.

Comment: You said there's a constant drip.  Do you know what that's from?  Have you tried not using the bathroom for a week to see if it goes away? (And then you could use other sealers)

Comment: @Nick2253 Not practical: we only have one bathroom!

Comment: That would indeed be impractical!  You might have a problem then.  Sealing an active leak is never easy.  Have you looking into a pipe wrap style sealer?

Comment: @Nick2253 No, I've not heard of that. Will investigate.

Comment: Silicone will not really stick to PVC. I'm surprised at the constant drip - it should only drip while you run water, after that the pipe should be empty. You can try some heavy-duty (i.e. very thick) PVC glue, but it needs to be dry.

Comment: FiberFix is awesome for these kinds of leaks. It's a temporary fix, but it works better than any other type of sealant.